# Error while building LLVM/clang

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, llvm-clang

I was trying to build LLVM/clang in HOME directory without sudo access following this link (http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html)

But when I type 'make' this happens

```
Error running link command: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [lib/libLLVMSupport.a] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/skataka/porple_tools/build'
make[1]: *** [lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/skataka/porple_tools/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
$ Write failed: Broken pipe
```

I have used make VERBOSE=1 and it says CMAKE-AR NOT FOUND

Edit:

Changed CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake file - SET(CMAKE_AR "path to llvm-ar")

Now I am getting "Error running link command: Permission denied"

Help me with this !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your build directory generated by cmake is broken it seems to not be able to find the linker. I'd clobber the build directory and regenerate it with cmake paying attention to if it spits out any errors while configuring.

Comment: Thank you Colin. I had tried what you said, but it was working in my computer, where I am a non sudouser.